# Is there a way to fill a cube up with fluid?

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

I am trying to make a fluid simulation render like this:

[image]

I don't want it to look like that, I just want a tank filled with water. **It needs to be a FLIP/APIC simulation** so I can use Effectors and more collision objects.

I know I can just do something like this:

[image]

And wait for the simulation to fill up the bowl, but that takes a long time to bake as it takes like 300 frames to fill up the bowl, so is there a way to do it quickly? If there is, I need it to be an actual simulation.

Please don't suggest doing something like this: making a cube look like water by sculpting it or adding a noise-displacement modifier and then adding a water/glass material on it as it needs to be a FLIP/APIC simulation:

[image: dummy model]
<sup>Dummy model (Sorry, I'm really bad at sculpting and the lighting sucks too lol)</sup>

Comment: You can increase the flow so that the space fills faster.

Comment: Does it need to flow in? or will flow in more later?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @Blunder downvote wasn’t me, but I would like to create something like this: https://bit.ly/3yoLIhC      That’s why I need it to be a simulation.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think the mix of air and water will be challenging

Answer (score 1):

Create a cube that is slightly bigger that your domain and give it a *Flow Behavior > Geometry*. If you want to drop an object into the water, give your object a *Fluid > Effector*.

[image]

Comment: You also can have additional Inflows to let more water in. (Just tested it because I wasn't sure)

Comment: sure, but doesn't he want still water?

Comment: I mentioned in one of the comments above that I would like to make something like this: https://bit.ly/3yoLIhC     So no still water wouldn’t work. And the link to the image is just a photo render, I would like an animation render

Comment: so you just need to drop objects that are Effector, not sure it will be very accurate though, the water won't be still, it will be animated by the effectors, but it is still at the beginning

Comment: @moonboots I've just mentioned it for people who didn't know (like me) so they can do a bathtub simulation ;-)

Comment: @Blunder, I don't know a lot either but from what I understand he's looking for Geometry, I guess he will have to tweak some parameters to have something realistic